Tensorflow is not detecting my gpu even though i installed CUDA and CudNn
I've tried to install TensorFlow on my machine so I can perform Ai model training. I've installed the CUDA and cuDnn models following this tutorial but even then when I tried running
import tensorflow as tf
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))

It output: 0
I've tried things such as installing the latest CUDA version and cuDnn version. Apparently since tensorflow doesnt have a standalone installation for Tensorflow-gpu im really in the lost here.
I ran nvidia-smi in the cmd prompt and it said CUDA Version: 12.6
Kindly help me with this.

You can install the fitting CUDA and CuDNN versions with pip install tensorflow[and-cuda] if you have a newer TF version. Otherwise, install CUDA/CuDNN via conda like this. Alternatively, you can check the official CUDA quickstarter guide. If you install CUDA by yourself, check out the tested build configuations to see which CUDA/CuDNN version should work fo sure for which TF version.

Newer versions of TensorFlow do not support Windows Native specifically for running on GPUs. I highly suggest to work on Windows WSL2 environment which runs linux Ubuntu. Just follow the steps in this link under Windows WSL2.
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip
